# Highcharts - show series values outside chart container?

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I'm wanting to show the values in my chart series outside the chart container in a label. I have the values inside a tooltip, how can I show these values outside the chart in another container on a label? [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bullrout/r32orj85/).

How can I show the series values in a label outside the chart on mouse over?

```
       mouseOver: function () {
                    console.log(chart.series)
                },
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

js:

```
//add this
    tooltip: {

                formatter:function(){
                          $('#tooltip').html(this.y);
                          return this.y;
                }
            },
```

html:

```
<div id="container" style="width: 600px; height: 350px; margin: 0 auto"></div>


<div id="tooltip"></div>
```

here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r32orj85/2/)

hope it helps

Comment: hi @amit_183, it does help, cheers, but I was hoping to have the tool tip and the value displaying in an outside div. The fiddle you posted has the tool tip blank.